# How to use the same dbcontext instance with multiple services by Injection or UnitofWork?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, dbcontext

I had discovered this architecture on the internet. I don't know there is a name of this architecture or not. If so, I will be pleased if you tell me the name.

Firstly,I want to explain how works this architecture to be able to get answer easily from you about my question.

As you see below, there may be one extra layer which is called Interface according to usual architectures. It was added to be able to reach BLL Layer from other projects than MVC like WCF, WEB API as well.

So, that is the closest layer to applications.

I wrote some codes inside of ninject injection for each entity as below for user

kernel.Bind< IUserService >().To< UserManager >();
kernel.Bind< IUserDAL >().To< EFUserRepository >();

When I write a parameter IUserService type in constructor method of a MVC Controller, according to settings above,  Ninject triggered and it gives an instance of UserManager for this parameter but Because constructor method of UserManager expects a parameter IUserDAL type, according to settings ninject triggered again and It gives instance of EFUserRepository for IUserDAL type parameter, again because constructor of EFUserRepository expects a parameter SoleusContext type, ninject triggered and gives instance for SoleusContext type parameter.

Finally I can reach DAL Layer by IUserService type parameter in 
MVC controller and I can realize database process.

But I have such a problem. When I write many different type Service references into MVC controller Constructor like IUserService, IAddressService, IProductService, each service use different instance of SoleusContext. I want to use same Context instance on all of the services which is defined constructor of Controller for per request.

According to my researches ıt is possible by creating generic unitofwork pattern for this architecture or doing some settings  on ninject.

I updated SoleusContext bind as InRequestScope() on Ninject. all services started to work with the same SoleusContext instance but I get error om some part of the project. I put an User instance into session on a request. Then when I tried to reach Addresses List which is located on User instance in session on the other request. I get this error. 
"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

If somebody tell me how I can use generic unit of work pattern on this architecture and How I can solve this problem, I will be so pleased. Thanks a lot.

MVC example UserController

```
namespace Soleus.MvcUI.Controllers
{
   public class UserController : Controller
   {
        IUserService _userService;

        public UserController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }
   }
}
```

Base Entity of  => Entity Layer

```
namespace Soleus.Entity
{
    public interface IEntity <TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    { 
        TKey Id { get; set; }
        DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

User Entity of => Entity Layer

```
namespace Soleus.Entity
{  
    public class User : IEntity<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public  string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
     }
}
```

BaseService of  => Interface Layer

```
namespace Soleus.Interface.Abstract
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService<TEntity,TKey> where TKey: IEquatable<TKey>
                                            where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
    {

        [OperationContract]
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();

        [OperationContract]
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetByCriteria(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

        [OperationContract]
        TEntity GetById(TKey id);

        [OperationContract]
        void Create(TEntity entity);

        [OperationContract]
        void Delete(TEntity entity);

        [OperationContract]
        void Edit(TEntity entity);

        [OperationContract]
        void Activate(TEntity entity);

        [OperationContract]
        int Save();
    }
}
```

UserService of  => Interface Layer

```
namespace Soleus.Interface.Abstract
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IUserService : IService<User, int>
    {
        [OperationContract]
        User GetByUsername(string username);

        [OperationContract]
        User GetByEmail(string email);
    }
}
```

Base Manager of => BLL Layer

```
namespace Soleus.BLL.Concrete
{
    public abstract class ManagerBase<TEntity,TKey> : IService<TEntity,TKey>   
                                                      where TKey: IEquatable<TKey> 
                                                      where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>

    {
        IDAL<TEntity,TKey> _DAL;

        public ManagerBase(IDAL<TEntity,TKey> DAL)
        {
            _DAL = DAL;
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _DAL.GetAll();
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetByCriteria(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _DAL.GetByCriteria(predicate);
        }

        public TEntity GetById(TKey id)
        {
            return _DAL.GetById(id);
        }

        public void Create(TEntity entity)
        {
            _DAL.Create(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            _DAL.Delete(entity);
        }

        public void Edit(TEntity entity)
        {
            _DAL.Edit(entity);
        }

        public void Activate(TKey id, string modifiedBy = null)
        {
            _DAL.Activate(id, modifiedBy);
        }

        public int Save()
        {
            return _DAL.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

UserManager of => BLL Layer

```
namespace Soleus.BLL.Concrete
{
    public class UserManager : ManagerBase<User, int>, IUserService
    {
        IUserDAL _userDAL;

        public UserManager(IUserDAL userDAL) : base(userDAL)
        {
            _userDAL = userDAL;
        }

        public User GetByUsername(string username)
        {
            return _userDAL.GetByUsername(username);
        }

        public User GetByEmail(string email)
        {
            return _userDAL.GetByEmail(email);
        }
    }
}
```

Base interface of => DAL Layer

```
namespace Soleus.DAL.Abstract
{
    public interface IDAL<TEntity,TKey>  where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
                                         where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();

        IQueryable<TEntity> GetByCriteria(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

        TEntity GetById(TKey id);

        void Create(TEntity entity);

        void Delete(TEntity entity);

        void Edit(TEntity entity);

        void Activate(TEntity entity);

        int Save();

    }
}
```

User interface of => DAL Layer

```
namespace Soleus.DAL.Abstract
{ 
    public interface IUserDAL : IDAL<User, int>   
    {
        User GetByUsername(string username);

        User GetByEmail(string email);
    }
}
```

Base Repository of => DAL Layer

```
namespace Soleus.DAL.Concrete
{
    public class EFRepositoryBase<TEntity,TKey> : IDAL<Tentity,TKey> 
                                                  where TKey:IEquatable<TKey>
                                                  where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>
    {

        protected readonly SoleusContext _context;

        public EFRepositoryBase(SoleusContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetByCriteria(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate);
        }

        public TEntity GetById(TKey id)
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        public void Create(TEntity entity)
        {
            entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            entity.IsDeleted = true;
            entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
         }

         public void Edit(TEntity entity)
         {
             entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
             _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
         }

         public void Activate(TEntity entity)
         {
             entity.IsDeleted = false;
             entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
         }

         public int Save()
         {
             return _context.SaveChanges();
         }
    }
}
```

User Repository of => DAL Layer

```
namespace Soleus.DAL.Concrete
{
    public class EFUserRepository: EFRepositoryBase<User, int>, IUserDAL
    {
        public User GetByUsername(string username)
        {
            return _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(i => i.UserName == username);
        }

        public User GetByEmail(string email)
        {
            return _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Email == email);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad... regarding DbContext, the correct way to inject DbContext in a web project, is with `InRequestScope()`:

```
kernel.Bind<ISomeService>().To<SomeService>().InRequestScope();
```

Make sure you **do not share the same dbContext among different requests**... and don't worry about performance: [according to MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#0cb87d0d-0981-48f1-ab1a-6fc0fdfa5e9f_c):

> A DataContext is lightweight and is not expensive to create. A typical
>   LINQ to SQL application creates DataContext instances at method scope
>   or as a member of short-lived classes that represent a logical set of
>   related database operations.

Also see [Proper Session/DbContext lifecycle management](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/12/20/proper-sessiondbcontext-lifecycle-management/)

---

Regarding Unit of Work, there is a lot of confusion around this pattern and I have seen some tutorials teaching how to implement UoW pattern using DBContext - what they don't realize is that DbContext already implements UoW pattern: [according to MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0):

> DbContext Class
>
> Represents a combination of the Unit-Of-Work and Repository patterns
>   and enables you to query a database and group together changes that
>   will then be written back to the store as a unit. DbContext is
>   conceptually similar to ObjectContext.

---

Regarding the session, I don't see how you are adding values to the session... and since your question is already too long, I recommend putting it in a different question. However, you need to keep in mind that using Session is not thread safe and there are different approaches for using session variables (e.g. storing them in cookie)

Comment: I watched some videos about unit of work. I have already known how to create unit of work pattern but according to videos they get repositories instances like ProductRepository, UserRepository from unit of work. But according to my architecture I should be able to get instances as a service like IProdutService, IUservice, as I get manual from Ninject in parameters of controller's constructor.

Comment: If you have watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM), please be careful... this course is not accurate and has caused a lot of confusion about UoW pattern and EF. As I have shown in the answer above, MS has already implemented UoW pattern in DbContext, and it does not make a lot of sense for you to wrap it around your own UoW pattern. –